# Django Channels sleep

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, channel

i have two group sends that i want to sleep between them, my code:

```
    await self.channel_layer.group_send(
    str(self.game_link),
    {
        "type": "group_message",
        "text": json.dumps(answer_data),
    }
    )

    await asyncio.sleep(5)

    await self.channel_layer.group_send(
    str(self.game_link),
    {
        "type": "group_message",
        "text": json.dumps(data),
    }
    )
```

what ends up happening is that both send at the same time after sleep ends.
how can i get around this?

Comment: That shouldn't be the case... How do you observe what's happening? From the client (browser)?

Comment: with console.log() in the front end when data received "socket.onmessage"